# USB Wireless Adapter not detected after suspend

Tags: wifi, suspend, usb-device

I am using an external USB wireless adapter (EnGenius Wirelss 11N) on Elementary OS Freya running on a Dell Vostro 1510.

Whereas the USB wireless is detected and connects when plugged in, it is not connecting after suspending the OS. In order to re-connect the wireless adapter, I must remove the USB connection and plug it back in again, at what point the adapter is detected and the connection established.

`lsusb` however returns the same list whether after suspending as after re-plugging the wireless adapter, namely:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1058:07a8 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 1740:9603 Senao RTL8188S WLAN Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2188:0ae1  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:63e0 Microdia Sonix Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

When removing the adapter, `Bus 002 Device 007: ID 1740:9603 Senao RTL8188S WLAN Adapter` misses from the lsusb output.

Funny thing: if I reboot the laptop, the device is detected and connection established flawlessly.

The expected behavior is the wireless adapter to be connected and detected, even after suspension of the OS.

Note: This problem used to happen as well on the same device, using different wireless adapters as well as 3G adapters on Ubuntu 12.4 and 13.4.

How can it be fixed?